# Инициализация переменных из файла

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо чтение переменных из файла.

Т.е. есть условный input.txt. В нем две строки:

```
a = 123
b = 321
```

Читаем файл и записываем в 'text'

```
with codecs.open('input.text', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
text = f.read()
```

Как реализовать инициализацию этих переменных, для дальнейшего использования. Например:

```
c = a + b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать таким образом:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('input.text', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    exec(f.read())
c = a + b
print(c)
```

Или так, чтобы записать в словарь:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dct = {}
    exec(f.read(), {}, dct)
c = dct['a'] + dct['b']
print(c)
```

Можно числа просто спарсить с помощью регулярных выражений в список:

```
import codecs
import re
with codecs.open('input.text', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lst = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
c = lst[0] + lst[1];  # Или c = sum(lst)
print(c)
```

Ну или в словарь:

```
import codecs
import re
with codecs.open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lst = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
    dct = {'a': lst[0], 'b': lst[1]}
c = dct['a'] + dct['b'];
print(c)
```

Comment: `exec()` не стоит для такого простого формата использовать, если у автора не явного требования произвольный Питон-код поддерживать.

Answer (score 2):

Для конфигурационного файла следует использовать самый простой формат, который работает в вашем случае. Это значит, что если вам не нужно произвольный Python код выполнять из конфига, то не используйте `exec()` для его чтения.

В вашем случае, можно руками формат распознать:

```
>>> {name.strip(): int(value) for line in file for name, value in [line.partition('=')[::2]]}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Или в виде функции:

```
def read_config(file):
    d = {}
    for line in file:
        name, eq, value = line.partition('=')
        if eq:
            d[name.strip()] = int(value)
    return d

with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    config = read_config(file)
```

Обратите внимание `codecs.open()` не используется.

Предпочтительно использовать уже существующие форматы/парсеры, такие как json, [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml):

```
import toml  # $ pip install toml

config = toml.load('input.txt')
# -> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

С небольшими изменениями, можно использовать [`configparser`, поддерживающий ini-подобный формат](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path

parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
parser.read_string('[DEFAULT]\n' + Path('input.txt').read_text('utf-8'))
config = parser['DEFAULT']

print(config.getint('a'), config.getint('b'))
```

Похожие решения в связанном вопросе: [How to remove the left part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599953/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
''' # input.txt
[Var1]
a = 1
b = 2
[Var2]
a = 3
b = 4
'''
from configparser import ConfigParser
p = ConfigParser()
p.read('input.txt')
print({s: {o: eval(p.get(s, o)) for o in p.options(s)} for s in p.sections()})
>>> {'Var1': {'b': 2, 'a': 1}, 'Var2': {'b': 4, 'a': 3}}
```